# How to solve below scenario in ssis?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I got a below error when running a package through SQL Agent jobs, but it will be fine for my local solution file.

> ERROR:
>       Column "MY COLUMN NAME" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types

That ssis package contains one data flow task, which is used to moving data from oracle to SQL server.

Any one solves this type of issue before.

Comment: Try checking the data types (along with sizes) of the columns on the Target table against the data that you are trying to pass.

Comment: Are both runnings (on your machine and by Job Agent) against the same servers? I actually doubt. So, if not, as @Praveen said, you need to check the data types and sizes of the columns where the Job Agent runs it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the datatype of the columns"MY COLUMN NAME" to DT_STR? This message indicates that a data flow component is trying to pass Unicode string data to another component that expects non-Unicode string data in the corresponding column. Please refer to the following link about it: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1393/import-excel-unicode-data-with-sql-server-integration-services/ [enter link description here](http://[http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1393/import-excel-unicode-data-with-sql-server-integration-services/][1])

Comment: Thanks for your Response, I've tried lots, all are working on my solution. But it's not working when I am running through SQL Jobs.